# How do I convert from ASCII to hex values and also increment char pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, hex

```
int main()
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile >> std::noskipws;
    size_t size = 0;
    infile.open("tworecords.dat", ios::binary);

    if(infile.is_open())
    {
        infile.seekg(0, ios::end);
        size = infile.tellg();
        infile.seekg(0, ios::beg);

        char *buffer = new char [size];
        infile.read(buffer, size);
        infile.close();

        for(int i=0; i <59; i++)
        {
            c1 = (*buffer);
            buffer++;
            cout << c1 << endl;
        }

        std::cout.write (buffer, size);
        cout << endl;
        delete[] buffer;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm reading in the data values from the file, and they appear in ASCII format. How do I make it so that I can see the values as hex values?

My second question is how do I increment char pointers to increase 1 by one, so that it reads one value at a time, like I am attempting to do in the code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might get you started. Annotated code:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // set integer output to uppercase-, hex-mode
    // with '0' as fill character for small byte values
    std::cout << std::hex << std::uppercase << std::setfill('0');
    // declare a buffer
    // note that you could use a std::vector<char> for your reads as well
    std::string input;
    // read a sequence of bytes (TODO: replace with reading from file)
    while(std::getline(std::cin, input)) {
        // iterate over the bytes as unsigned chars (not signed!)
        // to support characters in the negative byte value range (>7F)
        // (using C++11 range-based for loop)
        for (unsigned char i : input)
            // set width format for each value to 2 (00 to FF)
            // (setting is only active for the next insert operation)
            // insert the value as a multibyte integer
            // to get the proper basic_ostream::operator<< overload
            std::cout << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(i);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Usage Example:

```
$ g++ test.cc -std=c++11
$ echo "Hello World" | ./a.out
48656C6C6F20576F726C64
```

References:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/uppercase
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

---

As for your other question about how to iterate a character array, you have a couple of options. See this code example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // declare buffer and size
    // intentionally left out null-termination and sizeof()
    // for the purpose of this demonstration
    char buf[] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
    std::size_t size = 5; 
    // iterate using array indexing
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) std::cout << buf[i];
    std::cout << "\n";
    // iterate using pointer
    for (char *p = buf; p != buf+size; p++) std::cout << *p;
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Note that you can (and should) use a `std::vector<char>` as a buffer. This has some advantages. Biggest ones: trivial to pass in and out of functions, you can always call for the `size()` of the buffer, and, memory management is done by the standard library.

For example (untested code):

```
{
    // declare buffer of the appropriate size
    std::vector<char> buffer(size);
    // read data into the buffer
    infile.read(&(buffer[0]), buffer.size());
    infile.close();
    // iterate the buffer using std::vector<char>::iterator
    for (auto it = buffer.begin(); it != buffer.end(), ++it) {
        // do your output operations
    }
} // <-- storage duration of buffer ends automatically where the scope ends
```

More references:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto

Comment: `size_t size = sizeof(buf);`

Comment: @DyP or more generally `size_t size = sizeof(buf)/sizeof(*buf);` - I left this bit out to avoid confusion with dynamically allocated arrays where you just have a pointer when `sizeof` is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the hex-conversion I think your loop should be like the one below (see the comments):

```
    for(int i=0; i <size; i++)  // <-- size, not 59
    {
        c1 = buffer[i];         // copy the i'th element of buffer.  If you increment
                                // buffer (as in your example), you can't delete
                                //  it later because you lost the initial address
        cout << c1 << endl;
    }
```

Depending on the format of the hex numbers, if you want to output digit by digit (e.g. turn an 'A' into 10, etc. a very basic way is this:

```
    int dec; 
    if (c1>='0' && c1<='9') {
       dec= c1 - '0';   // e..g for '0' (ascii 48) it will make dec= (int)0.
    }
    else 
    if (c1>='A' && c1<='F') {
       dec= 10 + (c1 - 'A');   // e..g for 'A' (ascii 65) it will make dec= (int)10.
    }
    else {
         // should not happen or handle lower chase characters too
    }
```

Another way, using sscanf would be:

```
// convert one hex digit from c1 into a corresponding decimal number
char hex[2];
int dec;
hex[0]= c1;
hex[1]= '\0';
sscanf(hex, "%1x", &dec);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iomanip>

for(int i=0; i <size; i++)  // <-- size, not 59
{
    c1 = buffer[i];         // copy the i'th element of buffer.  If you increment
                            // buffer (as in your example), you can't delete
                            //  it later because you lost the initial address
    cout << hex << c1 << dec << endl;
}
```